# Facebook uncaught exception

Tags: facebook, proxy

I use Iframe for a facebook like button as follows.

```
 <iframe id="PageURL" src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<%= PageURL %>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=<%= LayoutStyle %>&amp;width=<%= Width %>&amp;show_faces=<%= ShowFaces %>&amp;action=<%= VerbToDisplay %>&amp;colorscheme=<%= ColorScheme %>&amp;font=<%= Font %>&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px;" allowTransparency="true">
    </iframe>
```

When my page loads it shows uncaught exception: Error: Permission denied for https://www.facebook.com to get property Proxy.InstallTrigger

in firebug. I can like the page but it doesnt show up on my wall any idea on this ?

Comment: this seemed to me causing due to recent FB security changes